# How to * char + * char in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers, merge, char

Here's a problem I've faced recently.

If I'll make something like this:

```
string str1 = "some";
string str2 = "thing";
cout << str1 + str2 << endl;
```

I'll get next output: `something`

But I only have this:

```
char *chr1 = "How do"
char *chr2 = "I do this?"
```

and I need to get the following output

So, *How do I do this?* And yes, I really need `char *` exactly.

Comment: If all you're doing is printing them you can just do `cout << chr1 << chr2 << endl;` Or if you actually wanted to add the space: `cout << chr1 << ' ' << chr2 << endl;`

Comment: Not just printing, I need to get char * variable as result container, which I need for futherer usage.

Comment: Have you considered using a `std::string` and just using it's `c_str()` method whenever you want a `const char*`?

Comment: So if you're trying to do this in a function and you try to do `return combined.c_str();` the returned `const char*` will go out of scope. @user2890591 I notice that you say your "app crashed" when you tried @Paranaix's solution. What I'm suggesting is you return an `std::string` and call `c_str()` *every time* you want to use a `const char*`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create buffer with size `strlen(chr1) + strlen(chr2) + 1 + 1`, (last `+1` since strlen returns length of string without null-terminator, but c-string should be ended with null-terminator) then copy first string in new buffer with `str(n)cpy` and then use `str(n)cat`.

```
char* buffer = new char[strlen(chr1) + strlen(chr2) + 1 + 1];
strcpy(buffer, chr1);
strcat(buffer, " ");
strcat(buffer, chr2);
// use buffer
delete[] buffer;
```

Comment: As the OP is a newbie, it might be a good idea why you allocate `+1` characters?

Comment: if you need deletion, rather use `boost::unique_ptr` in C++ or `std::unique_ptr` and `std::make_unique` in C++11.

Comment: sprintf is a good alternative to the cpy/cat/cat part of this.
ie. sprintf(buffer, "%s%s", chr1,chr2); and is handy for minor issues like tossing in a space between them if you want.

Answer (score 4):

Even though `strcat()` is probably the best solution as already mentioned by ScarletAmanranth, there is also another one.

One can also convert the c-strings to `std::string`'s first, perform any desired operations on them and then convert the result back to a c-string. This might better suit your needs in some cases.

**Example:**

```
const char* str1 = "foo";
const char* str2 = "bar";

std::string combined = std::string(str1) + str2; // notice std::string + char* => std::string

const char* result = combined.c_str();
```

**Advantages:**

- Can be written as oneliner, without any further delcarations of buffers etc.
- Might allow easier manipulation through `std::string` methods and related functions

**Drawbacks:**

- Additional overhead
- Only a `const char*` can be acquired, if a `char*` is required one must copy the c-string again

Consider that the returned `const char*` directly points to the internal buffer of the `std::string` object. Thus the pointer only remains valid as long as the `std::string` object does not run out-of-scope. Therefor using this with a temporary like this `const char* result = (std::string(str1) + str2).c_str();` is a very bad idea (whereas it would be legit to write someting like that in a function call, as the temporary remains until the call returns).

Comment: `c_str()` has `No-throw guarantee`. Make sure that the pointer only remains valid as long as the `std::string` remains valid. The acquired pointer directly points to the buffer of the `std::string` object. This is especially important if working with temporaries. I think i will inlcude this in my answere

Comment: What happens if you do a const_cast on the returned string by c_srt(), then modify the char*, then use c_str() again?

Comment: @lucas92 you can't do that, that's why the string class returns a **const** char*

Comment: @lucas92 When only seen from the standart it is simply undefined behaviour, because thats the case if you change a const-casted object. In technically terms I think everything will work fine as long as you do not change the size of the string. So replacing single chars with the `char*` should work. And btw, `c_str()` will probably return the same address both times.

Comment: I do this, its easy anf fast to write and works well if a const str is acceptable. If const is no good, then you have little choice but to go with on of the other techniques

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `strcat()` in such case.
As pointed out in the comments, you'll need something like `char[]` as a buffer for the new string.

Comment: But be careful, it's not possible to use any of the string pointers in the question as destination for `strcat`.

Comment: Done, application crashed at strcat() string.

Comment: @user2890591 That's because you did it wrong. This is why std::string is advised. It is easier.

Comment: @user2890591 There is an answer containing exact (and correct) use of the entire machinery, look at it :).

Answer (score 1):

Since this is C++, there had to be someone suggesting what I'm about to suggest. Use `stringstream`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char *chr1 = "How do";
    char *chr2 = "I do this?";
    stringstream ss;

    ss << chr1 << chr2;
    string result = ss.str();
    char* final = (char*) calloc(result.size()+1, sizeof(char));
    strcpy(final, result.c_str());

    cout << final << endl;

    delete [] chr1, chr2, final;

    return 0;
}
```

The `calloc(int size, sizeof([type]))` call alocates all the memory you need to keep your final `char*`. Like this, you can put two chars together ina  more C++ way. However, what you're wanting to do is more like C, but since you're in C++, might as well use methods that are part of C++ as much as you can.

Answer (score 0):

Several considerations:

- First [you should declare `chr1` and `chr2` as `const char *`,  not `char *`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) because attempting to modify a string literal is undefined behaviour.
- Second, `operator +` on pointers involves pointer arithmetics, `char *` is not special in this respect. If you need to concatenate strings, you need to allocate a buffer in which you copy the two strings one after the other.
- Existing answers make use of plain old C functions (except Paranaix'), but it would be more idiomatic in C++ if you made a stringstream that you use like `std::cout`:

  ```
  #include <string>
  #include <stringstream>
  std::ostringstream ss; ss << chr1 << " " << chr2;
  const std::string s = ss.str();
  const char *result = s.c_str(); // you can use this pointer during the scope of `s`.
  ```

Comment: "I need `char*`" -> "first, you should declare str1 and str2 as `const char*`" :)

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth, it is never too late to abide by good practices, String literals are const both in C and C++ and omitting the `const` is a mistake, and in C++11 it is even illegal.

Comment: Stackoverflow, the only portal where trolling is dismissed by reason :).

Comment: If I'll try to make this: *iNeedResultHere = result; I'll obviously get "a value of type "cost char *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "char *"", I know about const_cast, but it didn't help, iNeddResultHere (which is char *) contains unreadable set of characters after const_cast usage.

Comment: @user2890591, in both `C` and `C++` it is **undefined behaviour** to do something like `char *x = "abc"; x[0] = 'd';` and therefore you should never do that. Any string literal in your code must be considered as immutable. If you want modifiable character arrays, you **must** allocate a buffer to duplicate them, be it with `strdup` (C style), `new char[]...delete[]` (C++), `string` (C++), etc. or initialize as `char x[] = "abc"` because it initializes an array of 4 `char` from the string literal.

Answer (score 0):

The string concatenation was not necessary in the first place; you can continue using the stream insertion operator `<<` to perform effective concatenation (instead of using `+` to form one, temporary `std::string` object then stream-inserting that one resultant string):

```
std::string str1 = "some";
std::string str2 = "thing";
std::cout << str1 << str2 << std::endl;
```

And because this is a property of the stream and not the string, you can do it just as well with a `char*` input:

```
const char* chr1 = "How do "
const char* chr2 = "I do this?"
std::cout << chr1 << chr2 << std::endl;

// Output: How do I do this?
```

Notice that I added the *required* `const` for string literals; you may remove it if and only if your C-strings are not initialised by string literals.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the answer would be "use std::string".

> And yes, I really need char * exactly.
>
> Not just printing, I need to get char * variable as result container, which I need for futherer usage.

... but in this case:

```
#include <cstring>

std::size_t len1 = std::strlen(str1);
std::size_t len2 = std::strlen(str2);
// unique_ptr: automated lifetime management
// 1 for '\0' terminator
std::unique_ptr<char[]> buffer( new char[len1 + len2 + 1] );
std::copy_n(str1, len1, buffer.get());
std::copy_n(str2, len2, buffer.get() + len1);
buffer.get()[len1 + len2] = '\0'; // after this, buffer.get()
                                  // points to your string
```

Comment: Sooo... basically instead of just using a `std::string` as a container and calling `c_str()` to get the `const char*` you're suggesting that he use `std::unique_ptr<char[]>` as a container and call `get()` to get the `const char*`?

Comment: The OP pointed out that he _needs_ `char*`. As he doesn't specify why a std::string won't be OK we have to take him at his word. This is a char* - based solution, with RAII "safety" added in. The OP could use char* directly, but it requires an extra line (the `delete[]` call), adds no benefits and makes the code worse/less safe.

Comment: I love `std::unique_ptr` as much as the next guy, but I'm having a hard time seeing why this would be a good solution compared to say @Paranaix's. If you're going to introduce a container why not use the right one, right?

Comment: I know - normally I would simply suggest std::string ( as I actually did :) ). That said, if I were going use `char*` (as in "not std::string"), I would not store the result of std::string::c_str into a separate variable (passing down the stack is ok). Otherwise you end up with lifetime issues (the memory buffer will be invalidated when a variable - not the one holding the pointer - goes out of scope. That's a non-obvious bug waiting to happen (possibly when a second developer decides the pointer should be used for something else as well). In short, the code is not self-documenting.

Answer (score -2):

I share my code to be able to add the text of a 'char*' inside another auto* without the need to go through string or cstring:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

 int leng(char* tx){
     long long int n = 0;
     while(true){
         if(tx[n] == '\0'){
             break;
         }
         n += 1;
     }
         
     return n;
 }


int main(){
    char* t = "sffdsdssd";
    char* t2 = "axgdfb";
    long long int num = leng(t)+leng(t2);
    char g[num] = {0};
    long long int n = 0;
    for(n = 0; n < leng(t); n++){
        g[n] = t[n];
    }
    long long int num1 = leng(t);
    for(n = 0;  n < leng(t2); n++){
        g[num1+n] = t2[n];
    }
    char* resultado = (char*)g;
    cout << resultado;
    return 1;
}
```